# rails getting attributes of associated model for many objects in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, many-to-many

My title might be confusing, I wasn't sure what to write.

In rails I understand how to fetch **Many Objects** for **One parent object**

```
@first_user = User.first
@first_user_posts = @first_user.posts
```

But how can I fetch **Many Objects** for **Many parent objects** and select its attributes in one query?. I am trying to do something like that:

```
@many_posts = Post.all
@posts_by_user_gender = @many_posts.joins(:user).map(&:gender)
```

hoping it would give me an array that could look something like this:

```
@posts_by_user_gender => ["male", nil, "female", nil]
#I know I can do this map technique if I fetch it directly from the User model
# User.all.map(&:gender), 
# but I want to start with those that posted in a specific category
# Post.where(:category_id => 1)
```

and then to count the males I could use the [Ruby Array method .count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-count)

```
@males_count_who_posted = @posts_by_user_gender.count("male")
=> 1
```

I could always do 3 separate queries

```
@males_count_who_posted = @many_posts.select(:user_id).joins(:user)
                                      .where("gender = ?", "male").count
@females_count_who_posted = ...
```

but I find that extremely inefficient, especially if I do the same for something like "industry" where you could have more than 3 options.

Answer (score 0):

you can join model via SQL syntax

```
@posts_by_user_gender = @many_posts.joins("LEFT JOIN Users where users.id=posts.user_id").joins("LEFT JOIN Genders where genders.id=user.gender_id")
```

Comment: Sorry i did not make myself clear. Gender is an attribute of the User model. Its a string attribute that can be male, female or nil. I am thinking it could be Post.where(category_id => :category_id).joins(:user).select(:gender).map(&:gender). Then it gives me an array with all the itterations.

Comment: May be a call to map should look like .map(&:user.gender) or .map{ |x| x.user.gender}. Bacuse in this case it is Post object that goes to map method